# too many ActionController::Parameters type objects in my params object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am using nested parameters in my controller. the params are submitted through react forms. a form for the original object and a bunch of nested forms. the problem is that my `params` object has each object wrapped in an `ActionController::Parameters` object.

I expect only the main object to be wrapped in `ActionController::Parameters` and not every single nested object.

Debugging: the `params` object in the control looks something like this:

```
ActionController::Parameters {
 "_method"=>"post", 
 "authenticity_token"=>"kano3zIa5vs6JM6s/4fqqOQO61kq75IHlJglHGhlSOoI/yypu2nfV2cnS4VTKx0ENypFqE58wjB9Czq+T4Rbsw==",
 "campaign"=>

<ActionController::Parameters {
 "name"=>"12",
 "advertiser_id"=>"1", "revenue"=>"sd",
 "revenue_currency"=>"EUR",
 "start_date"=>"2020-05-27",
 "end_date"=>"2020-05-27", 
 "status"=>"done",
 "media_budgets_attributes"=>

<ActionController::Parameters {"0"=>
  <ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"",
   "_destroy"=>"false",
   "title"=>"asdf",
   "cost"=>"12",
   "cost_currency"=>"EUR",
   "affiliate_group_id"=>"1"} permitted: true>} permitted: true>} permitted: true>, 
   "controller"=>"campaigns",
   "action"=>"create"} permitted: true>
```

Notice that every object is wrapped with `ActionController::Parameters`. This makes it painful to permit params. I expect the `media_budgets_attributes` to be a plain array in `campaign` object. but media_budgets_attributes is wrapped with  `ActionController::Parameters`, which in its turn has a `ActionController::Parameters` objects in it.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Bro that is not readable.

Comment: what is not readable ?

Comment: The parameters man.  I edited it but I don't know what you're trying to do with the whole nested parameters.